# Who "owns" an Apiary Blueprint?

Tags: apiary

If I create a blueprint at apiary.io, then grant `Editor` rights to a few other folks, is there any lingering specialness about "me"?

If so, how can I figure out who "owns" the bp?

In particular, I have created Apiary accounts for several email addresses, and made them all editors. I'm now trying to use the CLI (github: apiaryio/apiary-client). It tells me "403 Forbidden" when I use a token generated (at login.apiary.io/tokens) for several "Editor" accounts. How can I pick the "true owner" account (which, obviously, I've forgot) to try the CLI against?

Comment: My question is not about legal issues (sorry, I can see why you might think that). When I say "owns," I mean "has unique software-mediated permission to modify." I know that all "Editor"s have the right to change the blueprint text, for instance, but does the original creator/owner have other rights? Perhaps "the right to invite other editors" or something?

Comment: I guess the owner can invite new editors, or toss out folks we doesn't want to be editors anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can find the owner name in the documentation header on the left, under the API Project name.

For team APIs, that would be the team name, for personal APIs, it's the name of the user.

To answer your initial question, the owner can access and change the API Settings (e.g. change API Project visibility, connect the API Project to GitHub, etc.). Additionaly, if the owner is a member of a team, they can transfer ownership of their personal API Project to the team.

Comment: Nada: and, I infer, there's no way to transfer ownership individual-to-individual (not the member-to-team transfer mentioned)?